# Using Spark window with more than one partition when there is no obvious partitioning column

Tags: sql, apache-spark, bigdata

Here is the scenario. Assuming I have the following table:

| identifier | line |
| --- | --- |
| 51169081604 | 2 |
| 00034886044 | 22 |
| 51168939455 | 52 |

The challenge is to, for every single column **line**, select the next biggest column **line**, which I have accomplished by the following SQL:

```
SELECT i1.line,i1.identifier, 
MAX(i1.line) OVER (
    ORDER BY i1.line ROWS BETWEEN 1 PRECEDING AND 1 FOLLOWING
)AS parent
FROM global_temp.documentIdentifiers i1
```

The challenge is partially solved alright, the problem is, when I execute this code on Spark, the performance is terrible. The warning message is very clear about it:

*No Partition Defined for Window operation! Moving all data to a single partition, this can cause serious performance degradation.*

Partitioning by any of the two fields does not work, it breaks the result, of course, as every created partition is not aware of the other lines.

Does anyone have any clue on how can I " select the next biggest column **line**" without performance issues?

Thanks

Comment: Not a Spark use case. You need a partitioning key, grouping key.

Comment: If I add a partition key, the "next biggest column line" will be computed by partition, and I need it to be evaluated for the whole dataset.

Comment: sure i get that, but there is no elegant way to do that...see 1st comment. i once did a mapPartitions or partitioned approach but it was fiddly

Comment: i see... using mapPartition would allow me to have some control over the max problem while still able to distribute the process when I use a regular map inside mapParition. I'll try that, thanks @thebluephanton

Comment: I will look it up tomorrow; the UI in SO is a little unhandy.

Comment: Use the partition and then process the boundaries as exge cases additionally

Comment: Cannot be done in SQL. Need to do in Spark DF API.

Comment: Not sure the parent 52 should be itself.

Comment: that could be fixed using ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND 1 PRECEDING, instead of having 52 as a parent of itself, we got null

Comment: I have a solution but is it faster. Does work in parallel but needs post processing and not just in sql

Comment: I had a solution but…is the line asc in the input?

Comment: Odd how question has more upvotes than answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using your "next" approach AND assuming the data is generated in ascending line order, the following does work in parallel, but if actually faster you can tell me; I do not know your volume of data. In any event you cannot solve just with SQL (%sql).

Here goes:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.Window
import spark.implicits._

case class X(identifier: Long, line: Long) // Too hard to explain, just gets around issues with df --> rdd --> df.

// Gen some more data.
val df = Seq(
 (1000000, 23), (1200, 56), (1201, 58), (1202, 60),
 (8200, 63), (890000, 67), (990000, 99), (33000, 123),
 (33001, 124), (33002, 126), (33009, 132), (33019, 133),
 (33029, 134), (33039, 135), (800, 201), (1800, 999),
 (1801, 1999), (1802, 2999), (1800444, 9999)
 ).toDF("identifier", "line")

// Add partition so as to be able to apply parallelism - except for upper boundary record.
val df2 = df.as[X]
            .rdd
            .mapPartitionsWithIndex((index, iter) => {
                iter.map(x => (index, x ))   
             }).mapValues(v => (v.identifier, v.line)).map(x => (x._1, x._2._1, x._2._2))
            .toDF("part", "identifier", "line")

// Process per partition.
@transient val w = org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.Window.partitionBy("part").orderBy("line")  
val df3 = df2.withColumn("next", lead("line", 1, null).over(w))

// Process upper boundary.
val df4 = df3.filter(df3("part") =!= 0).groupBy("part").agg(min("line").as("nxt")).toDF("pt", "nxt")
val df5 = df3.join(df4, (df3("part") === df4("pt") - 1), "outer" )
val df6 = df5.withColumn("next", when(col("next").isNull, col("nxt")).otherwise(col("next"))).select("identifier", "line", "next")

// Display. Sort accordingly.
df6.show(false)
```

returns:

```
+----------+----+----+
|identifier|line|next|
+----------+----+----+
|1000000   |23  |56  |
|1200      |56  |58  |
|1201      |58  |60  |
|1202      |60  |63  |
|8200      |63  |67  |
|890000    |67  |99  |
|990000    |99  |123 |
|33000     |123 |124 |
|33001     |124 |126 |
|33002     |126 |132 |
|33009     |132 |133 |
|33019     |133 |134 |
|33029     |134 |135 |
|33039     |135 |201 |
|800       |201 |999 |
|1800      |999 |1999|
|1801      |1999|2999|
|1802      |2999|9999|
|1800444   |9999|null|
+----------+----+----+
```

You can add additional sorting etc. Relies on narrow transformation when adding partition index. How you load may be an issue. Caching not considered.

If data is not ordered as stated  above, a range partitioning needs to occur first.

Comment: This is brilliant @thebluephantom, I'm converting it to java, thanks!

Comment: Brilliant would mean an upvote as well...stay with scala a lot easier than java